# How can I stop the outline on the left from collapsing?

Tags: lyx

I have my full outline on my left as I want it:

[image]

But now when I click on the end of the "aaa" line and press "Enter", the outline collapses to just "Part I":

[image]

Why? How can I stop the outline on the left from collapsing? I already have the "Keep" checked, but the outline pane still keeps collapsing.

This seems to be a very old bug (or feature?): https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6949

I'm using LyX Version 2.3.6.1 (Tuesday, December 29, 2020)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE 22 Feb. 2023: the bug is fixed (the code fix is [here](https://www.lyx.org/trac/changeset/41d95a45d96/lyxgit)). The fix will part of LyX 2.4.0 when it is released. Note that the fix relies on the outliner depth slider being set (as it is in the use case of the question).

Original answer:
Unfortunately this is a very old [bug](https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/6675) in LyX.

And although there are [many changes](https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX.NewInLyX24) in the upcoming 2.4.0 release, this bug is still not fixed (I reproduced with your same recipe) and there doesn't appear to be any progress on it (as you can see in the bug report).

Comment: Thanks for the info! (I guess I'll just put up with this for another 13 or more years.)

Comment: @user24096 The bug has been fixed and will be part of LyX 2.4.0 whenever it is released. Note that the fix relies on the outliner slider being set.